Nginx fallback conifguration
I'm using nginx to proxy requests to different containers:
server {
  listen 443;
  server_name example.com

    location /app1/ {
       proxy_pass http://container1:8080/;
    }
   location /app2/ {
       proxy_pass http://container2:8080/;
    }
   ....
}

This works fine when all containers are up and running. But if e.g. container3 is not running on startup, then nginx as a whole doesn't start. What I want is to achieve some sort of fallback configuration. To run all locations if possible, but if not, then just have locations running for essential containers e.g. container1 and container2 but not any other containers (location /app1/ and /app2/ but not /app3/).

  listen 443;
  server_name example.com

  # Check if container1 is reachable
  if ($upstream_container1_status != 200) {
    set $container1_down 1;
  }

  # Check if container2 is reachable
  if ($upstream_container2_status != 200) {
    set $container2_down 1;
  }

  # Check if container3 is reachable (optional, add similar checks for other containers)
  # if ($upstream_container3_status != 200) {
  #   set $container3_down 1;
  # }

  location /app1/ {
    # Only include this location if container1 is up
    if ($container1_down != 1) {
      proxy_pass http://container1:8080/;
    }
  }

  location /app2/ {
    # Only include this location if container2 is up
    if ($container2_down != 1) {
      proxy_pass http://container2:8080/;
    }
  }

  # Location for essential containers (if needed)
  location /app1/ {
    proxy_pass http://container1:8080/;
  }

  location /app2/ {
    proxy_pass http://container2:8080/;
  }

  # ... (other locations, if any)

  # Upstream configuration (assuming all containers have the same port)
  upstream container1 {
    server container1:8080;
    # Optional health check
    # server container1:8080 health_checks {
    #   interval 10s;
    #   fast_interval 5s;
    #   passes 2;
    #   # Set container1_down to 1 if health check fails
    #   unhealthy_status 429;
    # }
  }

  upstream container2 {
    server container2:8080;
    # Optional health check (same as above)
  }

  # ... (upstream definitions for other containers, if any)
}

something like conditional option might work but i am not sure.
